# Padre Complains that a Perl Module isn't installed when CPAN says it is

Tags: perl, padre

Padre IDE is complaining that:

> Can't locate Email/Send/SMTP/Gmail.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:\Users\me\mymodule C:/Dwimperl/perl/site/lib C:/Dwimperl/perl/vendor/lib C:/Dwimperl/perl/lib .) at myscript.pl line 21.

But `Email::Send::SMTP::Gmail` module is installed because in command prompt when I run `cpan Email::Send::SMTP::Gmail` I get the following message:

> Loading internal null logger. Install Log::Log4perl for logging messages
>   CPAN: Term::ANSIColor loaded ok (v4.06)
>   CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.56_01)
>   Reading 'C:\Perl64\cpan\Metadata'
>     Database was generated on Sun, 21 May 2017 04:17:02 GMT
>   CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v5.20170114_24)
>   Email::Send::SMTP::Gmail is up to date (1.06).

What the heck is going wrong? Note in Padre when I go to `Tools->Module Tools->Open CPAN Config File` I get the error dialog popup:

> Failed to find your CPAN configuration

Could this be part of the problem? I have searched the Padre help for `cpan configuration` but no results came up.

Any advice would be extremely helpful.

Comment: It appears that you've got two distributions of Perl installed, and the module you're trying to use is installed to the "other" one.

Comment: @MattJacob Yes I have activeperl and strawberry perl. Activeperl was to try and use Eclipse perl plugin but its not happy either. Any idea how I can setup my system (or just Padre) to know which perl to use?

Comment: No clue. I don't use Padre. One would think it would use your `PATH`, so what does that look like?

Comment: @MattJacob In my `PATH` env variable I can see all these perl references/paths: `C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;C:\Strawberry\c\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\site\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\bin;C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin;C:\Dwimperl\perl\site\bin;C:\Dwimperl\c\bin;`

Comment: If you only used ActivePerl to try using EPIC, why don't you just deinstall it using its installer? That way the PATH will be cleaned up and you'll end up with only Strawberry.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have two installations of Perl, one in `C:\Dwimperl`, and one in `C:\Perl64`. You are installing the module for the one in `C:\Perl64`, but you are using the one in `C:\Dwimperl`. Use the `cpan` that comes with the `perl` you wish to use.